# Difficulty with python urllib2 form-sending: website says I don't have cookies enabled though I should

Tags: python, cookies, urllib2, urllib

So, I'm trying to submit a form with urllib/urllib2 which should set some a cookie to log me in. However, the website seems convinced that "cookies are not enabled" though I've told urllib to process cookies.

This is what my code looks like:

```
opener = urllib2.build_opener( urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor() )
urllib2.install_opener( opener )
params = urllib.urlencode( { 'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass' } )

f = opener.open( 'http://example.com/login/',  params )
data = f.read()
print data # Returns a webpage which shows "You need to enable cookies!"
f.close()
```

What am I missing? I know I've used a similar recipe before for logging in.

Edit: On examining the headers that get sent when I fill the form out myself, I think I may be having the same problem asked (but not answered) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543951/302s-and-losing-cookies-with-urllib2) (the form responds with a 302 redirect). Hum.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2,urllib,cookielib

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener( opener )
params = urllib.urlencode( { 'username': 'user', 'password': 'pass' } )

f = opener.open( 'http://example.com/login/',  params )
data = f.read()
print data 
f.close()
```

try this.

Comment: Just did, though I did try something like that earlier. Didn't work, but I think the problem is that the form responds with a 302 redirect, which apparently causes urllib2 problems (see the edit above).