# Python CookieJar saves cookie, but doesn't send it to website

Tags: python, urllib2, cookiejar

I am trying to login to website using urllib2 and cookiejar. It saves the session id, but when I try to open another link, which requires authentication it says that I am not logged in. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code, which fails for me:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib

cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))

# Gives response saying that I logged in succesfully
response = opener.open("http://site.com/login", "username=testuser&password=" + md5encode("testpassword"))

# Gives response saying that I am not logged in
response1 = opener.open("http://site.com/check")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your implementation seems fine... and should work.

It should be sending in the correct `cookies`, but I see it as the case when the site is actually not logging you in.

How can you say that its not sending the `cookies` or may be `cookies` that you are getting are not the one that authenticates you.

Use : `response.info()` to see the headers of the responses to see what cookies you are receiving actually.

The site may not be logging you in because :

- Its having a check on `User-agent`  that you are not setting, since some sites open from 4 major browsers only to disallow bot access.
- The site might be looking for some special hidden form field that you might not be sending in.

1 piece of advise:

```
from urllib import urlencode
# Use urlencode to encode your data

data = urlencode(dict(username='testuser', password=md5encode("testpassword")))
response = opener.open("http://site.com/login", data)
```

Moreover 1 thing is strange here :

- You are md5 encoding your password before sending it over. (Strange)
- This is generally done by the server before comparing to database.
- This is possible only if the `site.com` implements md5 in javascript.
- Its a very rare case, since only may be 0.01 % websites do that..
- Check that - that might be the problem, and you are providing the hashed form and not the actual password to the server.
- So, server would have been again calculating a md5 for your md5 hash.

Check out.. !!
:)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am working on a client software for some service and I am directly communicating with the person who's implementing php server. Password needs to be sent as md5 hash for security reasons. And there aren't any hidden form fields. I'll try using mechanize or Curl.

Comment: Consider awarding the answer by giving it an up and accepting the answer by clicking the 'tick' next to the answer.

That is how you thank on stackoverflow.

Comment: @TomRay Hashing the password in this manner before sending it isn't actually securing anything--it's merely providing a *derived* password that is just as good as a password from a security perspective.  Whoever implemented that service was not thinking clearly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with my own test server, which worked fine with a browser, but not with the `urllib2.build_opener` solution.

The problem seems to be in urllib2. As [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543951/302s-and-losing-cookies-with-urllib2) suggest, it's easy to use more powerful [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library instead of urllib2:

```
cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.set_cookiejar(cookieJar)
opener = mechanize.build_opener(*browser.handlers)
```

And the opener will work as expected!